# NPM many SCSS files in many directories into one css file

Tags: css, node.js, npm, sass

I have a "static" directory with SCSS files. I have application components that live in another directory, each of which has an SCSS file.

I'd like to compile all of these files into one .css file in an output directory. One of the "static" SCSS files is a variables file that should be imported into all of the other files. I'd also like to not have to maintain the import paths in each of the components, and more may be added later.

This is the script I've tried, which seems to only find the "static" directory and outputs them as individual css files in `output/styles`. The documented node-sass commands are pretty light on explanation.

```
"scss": "node-sass --watch ./my/static/styles ./my/components -o ./output/styles --output-style compressed"
```

Comment: Have you used anything like  Gulp or Webpack to bundle/pack your files together before?

Comment: @CallistusAsirvatham So far just tried to do this with the package.json file scripts. Maybe I'm barking up the wrong tree here?

Comment: I would reccommend that you could use https://www.npmjs.com/package/scss-bundle, if you can share your directory structure (doesn't have to be real names) then may be able to help you build a script

Comment: @CallistusAsirvatham /assets/src (static stuff), /components (components in their own directories), /assets/styles (output directory)

Comment: Just want to check you main scss file has the imports for other files?

Comment: @CallistusAsirvatham I have no imports set up currently. Given the disparate nature of the individual component files (and they will be added/removed over time) the hope was that the scss build would simply grab all the existing .scss files and create an output file.

Comment: What you may néed then is to use something like gulp and the recursively search your directories to then pick up the files you need.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume this is not for a React project. If it is for React than there is a really good article here and it is relatively straight fwd. https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-sass-in-create-react-app-v2

Assuming a blank project in vanilla javascript this is what I do after running *npm init* and all that.

1. create and index.html file
2. create a css folder and scss/sass folder
3. inside the css folder create a style.css file
4. install *node-sass* as dev dependency
5. inside package.json file write a script like:

   ```
       "scripts": {"compile:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css -w"}
   ```
6. run the script inside your terminal using *npm run compile:sass*
7. install live server if you have not already done so, *npm i live-server -g*
8. you can import all your scss files ie. _header.scss _nav.scss, _variables.scss into one main.scss file create above.
9. You might also need to have a non-empty style.css file before you compiling. This will be overridden once your run *npm run compile:sass*